# Going from string to Base Ten in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I convert (`"1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0"`) to base ten.  I keep finding answers for converting lists to base ten but not for when I already have this string

Comment: `str.split` would probably be a good starting point.

Comment: That depends... While one might assume that the `1`s and `0`s there represent binary digits, they might just as well represent digits from any base greater than 2, as well, which would significantly change the process...

Answer (score 4):

You can use `str.replace` and [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function :

```
>>> s="1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0"
>>> int(s.replace(',',''),2)
178
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can slice:

```
int(string[::2], 2)
```